# Baked lighting seems to have no effect on Blender model

Tags: blender, unity-game-engine

I'm having a terrible time trying to figure out what's going on with my baked lighting. It appears that only Realtime lights affect my model. I've attached 2 images to demonstrate the problem. I have several point lights in the interior of my model. If I set them to Realtime everything looks great. However, if I set the, to Baked and change the GI accordingly they don't seem to interact with the model at all. Oddly enough the Directional Light on the exterior (and you can see it poking through the hallway door) Seems to display fine when set to Baked.

The model is generated in Blender and I do have the "Generate Lightmap UVs" import option selected. I've tried just about every combination of settings I can think of.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the interior lights were just a few pixels above the surface of my ceiling cube, causing the light to never reach the interior of the room :/